# How to store result directly to Database from Javascript itself

Tags: javascript

I have written a small Client Program using jQuery which call a web service periodically for different stocks like GOOG , APPL , IBM ., etc for every 2 seconds .

Is it possible I can store the response data  in any of the  Database  directly from Javascript itself ?? (Don't want to use any languages like JAVA , .Net .,etc) for this.

I see that there is no support for Mongodb from javascript directly ?

Is there any such database which allows to store data from javascript itself ?

Comment: Write APIs in server-side.. If you're familiar with Javascript then go for **`NODE.JS`**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API